# Recreational mathematics - Digit sum

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Find the **sum** of **all 3-digit positive numbers N** that satisfy the condition that the **digit sum** of **N** is **3 times** the **digit sum of N+3**

Can you help me with this question?

Comment: Do you allow zero as leading digits

Comment: Your formatting is extremely weird: why use bold italic throughout all the question? Plus, it sounds like you're giving us an order. People here usually downvote for that ) A good way to avoid this is to follow the rules from the [FAQ] when asking questions.

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 is not considered a 3digit number

Comment: SORRY I am new and i will edit this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering your question just because your'e new. Please format your questions better in the future.
Represent $N=100a+10b+c$. From the condition it is clear that $7\leq c\leq 9$ (otherwise the sum of digits in $N+3$ is $a+b+c+3$, which is greater than $a+b+c$).
Now we have two cases: $b<9$ and $b=9$.
(1) $b<9$ then the sum of digits in $N+3$ is $a+(b+1)+j$ where $j=0,1,2$. We have the equation:
$$3(a+(b+1)+j)=a+b+c\Leftrightarrow 2a+2b+3j+3=c$$
Since $c=7,8,9$, we have three possible options:
$$\begin{array}{l} c=7,j=0\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}2a+2b=4\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}a+b=2\\
c=8,j=1\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}2a+2b=2\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}a+b=1\\
c=9,j=2\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}2a+2b=0\hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow\hspace{5pt}a+b=0
\end{array}$$
From the first option you get three such numbers: $027,117,207$.
From the second option you get two such numbers: $018,108$.
From the third option you get one such number: $009$.

Do the same analysis for the case $b=9$. It is much easier.
This way you can find all such numbers and hence their sum.

Comment: so what is the answer

Comment: If you check the case when $b=9$, you will see that there are no such numbers. So the sum is $27+117+207+18+108+9=486$ if you allow $0$ as a leading digit (i.e. is $009$ a three digit number?). If not - then the sum is $117+207+108=432$